# MercadoPago no encuentra payments en sandbox mode

Tags: java, mercadopago, sandbox

estoy teniendo problemas en la integración de mercado pago en sandbox con java, cuando realizo un pago (con las tarjetas de prueba) supuestamente se realiza con éxito pero cuando quiero acceder a la información del pago con el collection_id que devuelve me dice que no lo encuentra.
Me podrán decir si estoy haciendo algo mal o hay alguna inconsistencia de datos en el sandbox de mercado pago? en la documentación dice que está en mantenimiento y que puede no funcionar como uno espera.
Les dejo el código:

```
public String createPayPreference(String title, String description, int quantity, double unitPrice) {
        MP mp = new MP(applicationProperties.getProperty("viajes.mercado.pago.client.id"), applicationProperties.getProperty("viajes.mercado.pago.client.secret"));

        String initPoint = "";


        String preferenceData =
                "{'items':"+
                        "[{"+
                            "'title':'" + title + "',"+
                            "'description':'" + description + "',"+
                            "'quantity':" + quantity +","+
                            "'currency_id':'ARS',"+ 
                            "'unit_price':"+ unitPrice +
                        "}]," +
                "'payment_methods': {" +
                    "'excluded_payment_types': [" +
                        "{" +
                            "'id': 'ticket' " +
                        "}," +
                        "{" +
                            "'id': 'atm' " +
                        "}" +
                    "]" +
                "}," +
                "'operation_type': 'regular_payment'" +
                "}";

        mp.sandboxMode(Boolean.valueOf(applicationProperties.getProperty("viajes.mercado.pago.sandbox.mode")));
        try {

            JSONObject preference = mp.createPreference(preferenceData);
            initPoint = preference.getJSONObject("response").getString(applicationProperties.getProperty("viajes.mercado.pago.init.point"));

        } catch(JSONException e) {
            logger.error("Error al generar la preferencia de pago de mercado pago: " + e.getMessage());
        } catch(Exception e) {
            logger.error("Error al generar la preferencia de pago de mercado pago: " + e.getMessage());
        }

        return initPoint;
    }


public void refund(Reservation reservation) {
            MP mp = new MP(applicationProperties.getProperty("viajes.mercado.pago.client.id"), applicationProperties.getProperty("viajes.mercado.pago.client.secret"));
            mp.sandboxMode(Boolean.valueOf(applicationProperties.getProperty("viajes.mercado.pago.sandbox.mode")));
            try {
                JSONObject response = mp.refundPayment(reservation.getPayment().getCollectionId());
                String status = response.getJSONObject("response").getString("status");
                String message = response.getJSONObject("response").getString("message");
                if(Integer.valueOf(status) == 200) {
                    logger.info("Se genero una devolución de pago total para la reserva: " + reservation.getId());
                } else {
                    throw new Exception("No se pudo generar la devolución del pago total para la reserva: " + reservation.getId() + " Código de error: " + status + " " + message);
                }
            } catch(JSONException e) {
                logger.error("Error al generar la devolucion de pago total de mercado pago: Reserva:" + reservation.getId() + " Error: " + e.getMessage());
            } catch(Exception e) {
                logger.error("Error al generar la devolucion de pago total de mercado pago: Reserva:" + reservation.getId() + " Error: " + e.getMessage());
            }


    }
```

La property de sandbox mode esta en true para el ambiente desarrollo, y el init_point es sandbox_init_point.
Saludos y gracias

Comment: Creo que no podes ver un pago en modo sandbox, por el hecho de que el pago en realidad no existe.

Comment: No tiene sentido, el pago debería existir de todos modos en modo sandbox, sino sólo se podrían probar pagos y ninguna otra funcionalidad en ese modo. gracias igual

Comment: Nico, te comento. El Sandbox está orientado a testear el flujo. Si mi respuesta no te convence, acá esta la respuesta oficial:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mercadopago-developers/jNHX9SgH3pk